# Verify email address without being logged in Laravel 8 (Sanctum)

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-sanctum

I want to allow users to verify email addresses without being logged in.

When the user registers, he gets a verification link. If he clicks on it he gets verified and automatically logged in because he gets logged in at registration. But if a user uses a different device to verify, lets say smartphone, he's unable to directly verify email because he's not logged in. How can I change my controller to be able to do that?

this is my controller:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\EmailVerificationRequest;

public function verify(EmailVerificationRequest $request)
    {
        if ($request->user()->hasVerifiedEmail()) {
            return [
                'message' => 'Email already verified'
            ];
        }

        if ($request->user()->markEmailAsVerified()) {
            event(new Verified($request->user()));
        }

        return [
            'message' => 'Email has been verified'
            //then front-end redirects user to login page
        ];
    }
```

and this is API:

```
Route::get('verify-email/{id}/{hash}', [EmailVerificationController::class, 'verify'])->name('verification.verify')->middleware('auth:sanctum');
```

If I remove `middleware('auth:sanctum');` I get `Call to a member function getKey() on null.`
Thank you!

Comment: Laravel checks logged in user from `$request` to complete email verification process. Maybe you can override built-in email verification mechanism to solve that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public function verify(Request $request)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($request->id);

    if ($user->email_verified_at) {
        return '';
    }

    if ($user->markEmailAsVerified()) {
        event(new Verified($user));
    }

    return redirect()->away('app://open'); // The deep link
}
```

Comment: Being by default a signed URL, we should also incorporate an email signature check `$request->hasValidSignature()`